# How to use #0 effectively in recursion?

Tags: recursion

Recently I am learning to use #0

for example: find the Max of a list.

```
Which[
# == {},                  "error",

Length@# == 1,             First@#,

#[[1]] > #0[Rest@#],       #[[1]],

True,                      #0[Rest@#]

] &@{1, 2, 3}
```

But since there are two `#0[Rest@#]` , I wonder how to reduce it into one.

> I know that `{1,2,3}/.{a_,b__}->{{a},{b}}` can split the list, But I don't know how to use it.(Or other way to achieve it)

Comment: Is there an example that requires recursion and can’t be solved by Max?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A direct answer to the question is to introduce a variable to hold the result:

```
fn2 =
  Which[ 
    # == {}, "error",
    Length@# == 1, First@#,
    #[[1]] > (temp = #0[Rest@#]), #[[1]],
    True, temp] &
```

Of course, you might not want temporary variables floating around, so you could introduce a Module or manage symbol name collisions some other way.

Although you didn't ask, there's another consideration. This implementation must build up an ever larger structure as it recurses, because it can't finish evaluating `#[[1]] > (temp = #0[Rest@#])` until it first evaluates `#0[Rest@#]`. So the left hand side is held onto while the right hand side is expanded. And, of course, this happens at every recursion step. So, if you want a bit more performance, you should eliminate this overhead, which we can do with a slightly different implementation:

```
fn3 =
  Which[
    # == {}, "error",
    Length@# == 1, First@#,
    #[[1]] > #[[2]], #0[Delete[#, 2]],
    True, #0[Rest@#]] &
```

This still leaves a bit to be desired. An even more iterative implementation gives more performance:

```
fn4 = Fold[Function[, If[Greater[##], #1, #2]], -Infinity, #] &
```

But of course, now we don't need `#0` at all, so this is probably deviating too far from your original question.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this avoids the temp variable and making the recursive call twice:

```
Which[
    #1=={},
        "error",
    Length[#1]==1,
        First @ #,
    True,
        Max[#1[[1]], #0[Rest[#1]]]
]&@{1,2,3}
```

It isn't how I would write the code but I think it answers the question.

Comment: Yeah, I tried for awhile to come up with something like that, but I discarded it, because `Max` is the function we're trying to define. I gave up after that because, yeah, this isn't the road we want to go down anyway.